# Get dispatched NGRX item in browser console

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, angular-ngrx-data

I am new in NGRX and i am using it in Angular2+ app.

I have 2 components **CREATE** and **READ**. I am using NGRX to dispatch a message string on click event from **CREATE COMPONENT**.
I dispatch string message to NGRX STORE from **CREATE COMPONENT** and show that string message in **READ COMPONENT's HTML FILE** successfully, like

> {{message | async}}

But now i want to get same string in my console and when i console same **message** variable of READ COMPONENT in READ COMPONENT's TS FILE, i get an object of store whereas i want to get the same string which is being displayed in READ COMPONENT's HTML file.

Is there a method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

message is be an observable, you should subscribe for it in the component.ts file

```
message.subscribe((msg) => {
 console.log(msg):
})
```